# trim() leaves a single trailing and leading space

Tags: php, trim

php 7.4

I believe php's trim is malfunctioning. It removes duplicate trailing and leading spaces, but it leaves a single trailing and leading space.

```
function string_to_safe_list($str){
    $list = explode(",", $str);
    array_map(function($x){
        return trim(strtolower(htmlspecialchars($x)));
    }, $list);
    var_dump($str);
    var_dump($list);
    return $list;
}
```

```
$str = "test,test, test, test   ,  test, test";
=> string_to_safe_list($str) = {"test", "test", " test", " test ", " test", " test"}
```

`$str` is a "comma seperated value" array.

How can I get `trim()` to behave properly and thus get `$list` to become `{"test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test"}`, without manually checking and correcting the first and last character of each string in `$list`?

It is unacceptable to delete every single whitespace instance however, because a valid `$str` might be `"test entry, test entry, test, test"` which should become `{"test entry", "test entry", "test", "test"}`

Comment: Run `var_dump` after `$list =` and show us the output.

Comment: @Marwelln it looks like `array(6) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> string(4) "test" [2]=> string(5) " test" [3]=> string(8) " test " [4]=> string(6) " test" [5]=> string(5) " test" }`, which is to be expected. The later `array map trim` call should fix the leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: You're just not returning anything from your function.

Comment: @El_Vanja I forgot to paste the return, fixed

Comment: If you look at the docs of [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map) you'll see that it's not modifying the original array, but rather returning a new one. And note that you can directly return the `array_map` result without having to store it in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the result of array_map to a variable.

```
function string_to_safe_list($str){
    $list = explode(",", $str);
    $list = array_map(function($x){
        return trim(strtolower(htmlspecialchars($x)));
    }, $list);
    return $list;
}

$str = "test,test, test, test   ,  test, test";

var_dump(string_to_safe_list($str));
```

Comment: This is an incomplete solution. You're not returning anything from your function.

Comment: @El_Vanja But it's the source of the problem that is being answered...

Comment: @Luuk Sure, source. But no explanation is involved and, thinking of any future readers that might see this, it'd be wise to make a complete solution or otherwise they might try and use it `$myVar = string_to_safe_list('some,string,whatever')` and wonder why it isn't working.

Comment: @El_Vanja: True problem solvers look at the manual of [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map) which has information about "Return Values".

Comment: @Luuk If we were to go by that, this question wouldn't have existed in the first place. Most people that frequent this site aren't true problem solvers. I salute the answerer for editing.

Comment: I added the return statement for future readers as @El_Vanja suggested